# Microsoft Outlook API and Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, api, outlook, exchange-server

How to access a microsoft outlook API using swift. I want to use the microsoft outlook api to allow a user to search for people in a certain outlook server. the search framework is already set up. I am just really confused with how to even access the server. The code is mostly from consulting people who have done this before. This is the code that I have so far:

```
class ExchangeAPI {

func HTTPsendRequest(request: NSMutableURLRequest, callback: (String, String?) -> Void) {
    //implementing core data

    var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Emails", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    var email = Emails(entity: ent! , insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(
            request,
            completionHandler: {
                data, response, error in
                if error != nil {
                    callback("", error!.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    callback(
                        NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String,
                        nil
                    )
                }
        })

        task.resume()
    }



 func HTTPGet(url: String, callback: (String, String?) -> Void) {
//implementing core data
var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Emails",inManagedObjectContext: context)

var email = Emails(entity: ent! , insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    HTTPsendRequest(request, callback: callback)
        request.URL = NSURL(string: "https://mail.SAP.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

}




 }
```

Comment: Take a look at the [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article which explains possible options.